# Emulator closed after quick boot state selection

Tags: android, android-emulator

After run my emulator a pop up is showed asking me about the quick boot state:

[image]

If I press the button `Yes` the emulator is closed, If I press `No` closed as well. If I close the pop up the emulator is keep always with the screen black.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: did you figure it out? I am having the same issue.